How to override https createConnection without loosing certs in nodejs?
I am trying to override the createConnection field of https.requests, but can't figure out a way to do so without certificate errors.
When the createConnection field is not set, the requests works without any certificate errors.
When using net.createConnection, it yields a socket error.
When using tls.conenct, it yields a self signed cert error.
When using options._defaultAgent.createConnection, it also yield a self signed cert error.
When rejectUnauthorized is set to true, the request works with tls.connect and _defaultAgent.createConnection. But as the target is google with valid certificate, I don't get why I would need to disable that verification.
Eventually, I'd like to mutate options, but for now, I am just trying to log it without breaking the request.
Any pointers?
node v20.12.0, typescript v5.4.5.
import * as https from "https";
import type { RequestOptions } from "https";
import type { ClientRequestArgs } from "http";
import type { Duplex } from "node:stream";
import type { LookupOptions, LookupAddress } from "dns";
import * as tls from "tls";
import * as net from "net";

const options: RequestOptions = {
  hostname: "www.google.com",
  port: 443,
  path: "/",
  method: "GET",
  // rejectUnauthorized: false,
  // createConnection: tls.connect, // Self signed error.
  // createConnection: net.createConnection, // Socket hung error.
  // createConnection: (options: ClientRequestArgs, oncreate: (err: Error | null, socket: Duplex) => void): Duplex | null | undefined => {
  //   return (options._defaultAgent as any).createConnection(options, oncreate);
  // },
};

https
  .request(options, (res) => {
    let data = "";
    res.on("data", (chunk) => {
      data += chunk;
    });
    res.on("end", () => {
      console.log("StatusCode:", res.statusCode);
      console.log("Body:", data);
    });
  })
  .on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("Error: ", err);
  })
  .end();

